# Is there possible we use <? to <?php

Tags: php

Is there a way to enable php to understand `<?` notation instead of the default `<?php` notation to define a php syntax?

Appreciate your comments and suggestion.

Comment: sorry, I cant write <'question mark'

Comment: Your writing is a bit confusing, do you mean if there is another method instead of using <? or <?php to declare php?

Comment: Is that update correct?

Comment: Do a search and replace on all files? Or are you thinking of something else.

Comment: enable short tags; done like dinner

Comment: dinner is in the oven

Comment: not the goat I hope? it's not time yet and am only up to 3 hail Dagons

Comment: i have *other* plans for the goat, nuge-nuge wink-wink https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ona-RhLfRfc

Comment: go easy on it @Dagon and be sure to wear one of those goat things for your *you know what, wink wink, nudge nudge*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `php.ini` to accept the short notation of php's syntax. Look in `php.ini` and look for `short_open_tag` and set to `On`. After you are done save it and restart Apache or Nginx (whichever you use).